# How to copy a database backup file to another server in SQL Server Agent job

Tags: sql-server, copy, sql-server-agent

I realize I'm probably missing something simple, but I can't figure it out.

If I use the following "copy" command in a batch file on the destination server, it works fine.  However, if I add it in a step on the SQL Server Agent job that does the backup, I get a syntax error.  So, what am I doing wrong?  It seems like it might be getting stuck on the "/" on the "/y" parameter, but I do want it to overwrite the existing file.

```
copy /y "\\DBServer\c$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\db_daily.bak" "\\DESTINATION\\db\db_daily.bak"
```

The error is:

```
Incorrect syntax near '/'.  [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102).  The step failed.
```

I removed the /y altogether and tried everything I can think of.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a batch expert, but I'm pretty sure you need to use [xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). With that being said, I'd check our [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) if you are into powershell integration with SQL Server. I'm also a fan of using Windows Task Scheduler and keeping batch and ps files external to SQL Server... just schedule those on the windows side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your step was created as Type "Operating System (Cmd Exec) not as transact sql.

Or use the XP xp_cmdshell

```
   exec xp_cmdshell 'copy /y "\\DBServer\c$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\db_daily.bak" "\\DESTINATION\\db\db_daily.bak"'
```

Please note you may need to enable the xp_cmdshell.

Comment: You do not need to enable xp_cmdshell but your agent service must run under a security account that has permissions to access all the file shares.

Comment: You need to enable it,  because it is disabled by default at the installation time. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/xp-cmdshell-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: it is true that xp_commandshell is disabled by default, but it does not need to be enabled in order for Type "Operating System (Cmd Exec) job steps to run successfully.

Comment: It was never specified it was required for cmd exec jobs, It says: 
"Make sure your step was created as Type "Operating System (Cmd Exec) not as transact sql.

**Or** use the XP xp_cmdshell"
not sure where the confusion was.

Comment: Sorry... I shouldn't skim read.  You definitely do have to enable xp_cmdshell to exec xp_cmdshell :)